# Apache with django and wordpress, wsgi error loading wordpress

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, wsgi

I have two sites, site-one is a django app and site-two is a wordpress site.
I have two .conf files inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

#### `site-one.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin adminmail@gmail.com
    ServerName site-one.com
    ServerAlias www.site-one.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-one.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-one.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-one.com.access.log combined

    Alias /static /var/www/site-one.com/public_html/static
    <Directory /var/www/site-one.com/public_html/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/site-one.com/public_html/MyApp>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site-one.com/public_html/MyApp/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/var/www/site-one.com/public_html
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>
```

#### `site-two.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin adminmail@gmail.com
    ServerName site-two.com
    ServerAlias www.site-two.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site-two.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-two.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-two.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The site-one.com is 100% working but when I load site-two.com I get this error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

The site-two.com.error.log shows this:

```
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.629460 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056] mod_wsgi (pid=2396): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/site-one.com/public_html/MyApp/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.631915 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056] mod_wsgi (pid=2396): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/site-one.com/public_html/MyApp/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632702 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632776 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/var/www/site-one.com/public_html/MyApp/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632784 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632794 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632799 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632808 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632813 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632822 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632827 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632835 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632840 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632849 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632854 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632862 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632867 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632875 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632884 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632893 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632902 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632910 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632919 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632928 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Nov 02 09:09:48.632948 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 2396] [remote 151.49.10.216:63056] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyApp'
```

I am not an expert on apache config files so I can't understand why WSGI is called when I'm requesting site-two.

How can I solve this problem?

The `site-one.com.eror.log` file is empty by the way

Comment: The config files belong in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, but for the sites to be enabled you need symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. You can use `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` to enable and disable the sites.

Comment: I've already done it for both sites and also a2dissite the 000-default.conf file.
And of course restarted apache

Comment: Does `site-two.com` work if you disable ` site-one.com`? Note that using made-up domain names might be hiding the problem.

Comment: I tryied now but with no luck!

`a2dissite site-one.com`
`systemctl reload apache2`

I replaced the site-two (wordpress) with a html page as a test and I get the same error